# PHP DOMDocument difficulty with urlencoded characters in filename

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a routine that saves xml fragments as standalone documents.  The filename is generated from one of the elements which *may contain* characters that are undesirable in a filename - such as a space or `/`.  To get around this I `urlencode()` the filename first so instead of:

```
ABC DEF/123.xml
```

I end up with:

```
ABC+DEF%2F123.xml
```

This works fine as far as the filesystem is concerned but for some reason `DOMDocument::load` and `DOMDocument::save` both decode `%2F` and interpret it as a literal `/`.

This is easy enough to reproduce:

```php
$filename = urlencode('ABC DEF/123.xml');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->save($filename);
```

> PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::save(ABC+DEF/123.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in php shell code on line 1

For a simple workaround I am doing this:

```
file_put_contents($filename, $dom->saveXml());
```

My question is, why do these methods behave this way? And is there a property I can set or some other way to make those methods work so I can use DOMDocument methods instead of `file_put_contents()` or the like?

**UPDATE:** Looking at the [php source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/0f7f1498be549f5988bf9d8150f35bedf70741c5/ext/dom/document.c#L1571) it appears that the file handling is delegated to [`xmlSaveFormatFileEnc()`](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/libxml2/blob/master/xmlsave.c#L2514) which is said to "*Dump an XML document to a file or an URL*." Presumably the filename is given this treatment since it might also be an actual url. This still leaves me with a lot of questions.  Would appreciate someone well versed in `C` or familiar with `libxml2` to comment further or provide a real answer about what's going on here.